# Saving a Civi Report- too many redirects error

Tags: civireport, redirect

I'm trying to save a contact summary report after amending filters.

After each attempt to save I get a too many redirects error.

I can see the new instances in the civicrm_report_instances table, but the reprots aren't saving to the navigation menu as expected. If I try and reconstruct the report url with the new report instance id, I also get the too many redirects error message.

Drupal 7.69 Civi 5.19.4

-added 11/2/20
Just tried again. The error message is showing after saving report instance, and the url is to the new report instance. So it looks like it is being created, but is at the same time inaccessible. Perplexing.

[image: screenshot-of-error message]

Comment: did you refresh result before saving the report?

Comment: No. But I just tried that, and got the same result